# Can I use CSS to create this scrolling behavior or should I use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for suggestions on what to continue researching. I'm trying to create a different scrolling behavior on this website— http://schipperbros.com. The image slider in the "work" section and the white "about" section are to be fixed while the blue introduction section, orange logo section and the last section, "contact" scroll freely.

I basically want it to work like this site http://https://codyhouse.co/demo/alternate-fixed-scroll-background/index.html. The fixed portions of my site will be like the images in this site. This site uses background-attachment:fixed but I don't believe I can use this because my fixed areas are not just a single image—one of my sections is an image slider and the other is made up of copy.

Any thoughts what I could implement or a direction on what I can look for would be very helpful. Thanks you!

Comment: Look into `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: You can use [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds).

Comment: So would it be possible to use background-attachment: fixed; with an image slider? and would it be possible with a section that only has words (no images)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me tell you what you are wishing to achieve is known as **parallax scrolling effect**. There are tons of resources you can find.

Now coming to your original question, there are certain websites which use pure css to achieve parallax scrolling. Try this

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

The key is to use CSS3 transformations. You can refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp to find simple examples of CSS3 to understand code in the above website (keithclark).

This should come in handy if you are willing to use JS:-
http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/parallax/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple example using only CSS. It uses `background-attachment: fixed;`. Keep in mind `background-attachment` is not [supported in Opera Mini or the Android browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment).

```css
html,
body {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.background > div {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.background1 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background1);
}

.background2 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background2);
}
.background3 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background3);
}
```

```html
<div class="background background1">
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="background background2">
    <div>A Second Page</div>
</div>
<div class="background background3">
    <div>A Third Page</div>
</div>
```

Here's the working demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/LLv5q5p6/);

Comment: This is the effect I'm looking for but I don't believe that I could use the background-attachment:fixed for an image slider or a section filled with words. It seems like the background-attachment could olyn be used with a single image. Is that correct?